# What does "selection" mean? What about $.fn?

Tags: jquery

In [jQuery Learning Center](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/dollar-object-vs-function/):

> - Methods called on jQuery selections are in the `$.fn` namespace, and    automatically receive and return the selection as `this`.
> - Methods in the `$` namespace are generally utility-type methods, and do    not work with selections; they are not automatically passed any 
>     arguments, and their return value will vary.

I'm not sure what "selection" and `$fn` mean here. Does "selection" mean DOM element(s) selected using Sizzle? Is the `$fn` an object (since JavaScript/ECMAScript has no built-in support for namespaces) and the methods for this object are something like `$.fn.add()`?

I searched "jQuery selection" on the web but didn't get anything that looked promising. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Examples (and explanations) are much appreciated.

Comment: In part, duplicate of [What does jQuery.fn mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean)

Answer (score 2):

A jQuery selection is simply a call of the jQuery method itself (or the $ alias). It's like `$("#myDiv")`. In this case, `$("#myDiv")` is a selection. The result of this method is a jQuery object that contains all DOM elements that **match** your selection. The string you pass to $, is a **selector**. jQuery supports CSS selectors (eg: #myDiv, .myDiv or div), XPath selectors (eg $('/html/.//div[@id="text"]')) and others. Take a look at [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

`$.fn` is the "container" of functions available to selections. Let's say you have a plugin called `autocomplete`. If you define `autocomplete` in `$.fn`, then `autocomplete` is automatically available in any selection. Meaning you can call `$("#myDiv").autocomplete()`. In the `autocomplete` implementation you can access the matched DOM elements and apply the plugin to them. You can see how you can implement a simple plugin [here](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The text below the paragraph I quoted says: "There are a few cases where object methods and core methods have the same names, such as `$.each()` and `.each()`." What are object methods and core methods here? Are they methods of the `jQuery` object and methods of standard built-in JavaScript objects, respectively?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors are actually CSS selectors. So for example, `$('#some_HTML_element_id')` will return this element as jQuery object.

What is jQuery object? - A HTML like object which normal Javascript properties, same as - `document.getElementBy*()`, but with more functionality related with jQuery. For example:

```
jQuery('any selector').next() // selecting the next sibling element.

// there is no .next() function.
document.getElementBy*('any selector').next
```

This is the selection. You just selecting an element, and jQuery adding more functionality. It returning `this` element so you can use chaining. For example:

`$('.tab').eq(0).next().select()`

`$('.tab')` -> returning the jQuery set of objects because you are selecting `.tab` css class, in most cases, you will have more than one tab.

`jQuerySetOfElements.eq(0)` -> returning first element from the set. (in this case the first tab as jQuery object).

`jQueryFirstTab.next()` -> selecting next sibling element as jQuery object.

`...`

- Methods in the $ namespace are generally utility-type methods, and do not work with selections; they are not automatically passed any arguments, and their return value will vary.

This means utility-type function, that are not based on selectors. For example we have `$.each()`. As we know Javascript doesn't have foreach loop. So jQuery provide this function for us. See the syntax:

`$('selection')` --> returning jQuery elements.

`$.UtilityFunction()` --> Do some work for us.

- Methods called on jQuery selections are in the $.fn namespace, and
  automatically receive and return the selection as this.

This means that the selected elements with the selector, have the functions in the `$.fn` namespace, For example: in the `$.fn` namespace we have all the function that helping us to work with elements like: `.hide()`, `.show()`, `.toggle()`. When we select elements with selection, we can use this functions on the selected element, for example: `$('#myDiv').hide()`.

$.fn is jQuery.protopype. See this: [jQuery fn namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527031/jquery-fn-namespace)